# C# IoC Project Structure Standards

Tags: c#, mvvm, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

What is the recommended folder structure for a IoC C# project? For a MVVM project, the standard is to create folders named Views and ViewModels (and where do you put interfaces and unit testing classes?)

What about a DLL project, that has no views, but exposes many classes to be created via IoC, which folders should be in my project?

Also as I'm starting to refactor code into IoC, I'm running into issues with the SettingsFile class that contains data that is serialized into a file. It contains a few methods:

- void SetDefaultValues()
- SettingsFile Load()
- void Save()
- string Validate()
- SettingsFile Copy()

The main issue is with Load, as deserializing the object creates a new hard instance of the class, bypassing the principles of IoC. What's the right way of handling the scenario?

I'm thinking of moving all code outside of that class so that this class is only responsible for being serialized/deserialized without any code, and then excluding it from IoC. Is this the right thing to do? It's a similar problem when using Entity Framework and using any auto-generated table classes.

Thanks

Comment: `SettingsFile` sounds like a proxy for a `ConfigurationManager` or .net Core's `IConfiguration`. I'd recommend separating the concerns - most likely, a lot of things need to READ the config, and maybe not so many need to write. You can then lazy-load the config each time a service in the composition tree needs it. Windsor has support for factory methods.

Comment: Where does ConfigurationManager stores its settings file? There are only like 10 basic settings in the app that need to be loaded on startup so I wouldn't worry about lazy-loading. ConfigurationManager could be an option, but doing it my way has the advantage of being strongly-typed, instead of having to parse each value manually. I do however want to separate the config file content from the way it is being stored. As a Windows app, I want it serialized on the drive, but if the DLL is used in a Web app, the storage would be different.

Comment: you can have strongly-typed configuration since at least .net 4: http://blog.danskingdom.com/adding-and-accessing-custom-sections-in-your-c-app-config/

The config manager is used to get data out app.config and web.config files placed next to binaries; however you can also specify the file location...

Comment: Once installed into Program Files, the app doesn't have write access to that folder.

Comment: if it doesn't, why do you have the `Save` method?

Comment: I store the file in Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)

Comment: If I just create ISettingsFile interface around SettingsFile, then I can keep the same structure while exposing just the interface. Still, XmlSerializer doesn't work on interface and requires specific class type. I can also move LoadSettings and SaveSettings into a class that deals with all file IO access, since that's a completely separate thing than holding settings data. But then, SettingsFile remains with OS-specific code for path default values and validation -- where should this code go? Or I can leave it like that but it doesn't feel very clean.

Comment: Arg no I cannot keep the Load/Save/Validate code within SettingsFile. I cannot call Load to create a new class without already having a dummy instance of the class, and more importantly, when deserializing, it will not inject the dependencies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to separate data classes from behavior classes. SettingsFile, as well as any EntityFramework class, contain purely data. Dependency Injection via IoC applies only to behaviors classes.